# Products of linear forms in 3 variables

Tags: nt.number-theory

We say that a linear form $f=ax+by+cz$ of real coefficients is "irrational" if $a,b,c$ are linearly independent over the rationals. My question is: Are there 3 such "irrational" linear forms $f_1,f_2,f_3$ such that the product $f_1f_2f_3$ is of integral coefficients?

Note that for the "2-dimensional" analogue, we have $(x+\sqrt{2}y)(x-\sqrt{2}y)=x^2-2y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

How about $x+2\cos(2\pi/7)y+4\cos^2(2\pi/7)z$, 
$x+2\cos(4\pi/7)y+4\cos^2(4\pi/7)z$, 
$x+2\cos(6\pi/7)y+4\cos^2(6\pi/7)z$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but we are saying real linear forms...

Comment: Just take a totally real cubic field instead. Davenport studied such products a lot.

Comment: Could you give an explicit example or a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Take any irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 3 with real roots, say $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Set $f_1 = x + \alpha y + \alpha^2 z$, $f_2 = x + \beta y + \beta^2 z$, $f_3 = x + \gamma y + \gamma^2 z$. You can find plenty of polynomials <a href="http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~voight/nf-tables/3-25.txt">here</a>.

Comment: @lonekite, Robin's forms are linear. The cosine terms are numerical coefficients of the indeterminates $y$ and $z$. 

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, I understand. Robin first gave an example of complex linear forms with the same property, then revised it using the cosine function. Anyway, both Robin's example and felix' are very helpful to me. Thank you all.

Comment: @lonekite, sorry, didn't occur to me to check the editing history. 